El estado no se actualiza correctamente desde un hook hacia arriba en React
Tengo el siguiente hook:
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { useState } from "react";
    
    export const useAxios = () => {
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
        const [error, setError] = useState('');
        const [success, setSuccess] = useState('');

    const baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/api";

    const axiosFetch = async (endpoint, method = "GET", data = null, headers = {}) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setError(null);
        setSuccess(null);

        return axios({
            url: `${baseURL}${endpoint}`,
            method: method,
            data: data,
            headers: headers,
            withCredentials: true
        })
            .then(response => {
                
                setSuccess(response.data.mensaje || response.data);
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                
                const errorMessage = err.response?.data.error || "Ocurrió un error";
                setError(errorMessage);
                return null;
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    };

    return { isLoading, error, success, axiosFetch };
};

El problema es que al leer el estado de error o success en la función de otro hook que lo usa (handleSubmit) no se actualiza correctamente, el servidor sí responde bien (verificado) pero cuando hago la 2da llamada ahí es cuando veo el estado, el estado va subiendo de componente en componente hasta llegar a un modal y esto es un problema que no sé cómo solucionar, el otro hook que utiliza a este tiene la siguiente estructura:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useAxios } from "../useAxios";

export const useValidacionLogin = (idForm, tituloBotonPrimario) => {

    const { isLoading, error, success, axiosFetch } = useAxios();

    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
    const [modalError, setModalError] = useState(false);
    const [modalTitulo, setModalTitulo] = useState('');
    const [modalMensaje, setModalMensaje] = useState('');


    //código que omito hasta lo que importa

    // Manejar el envío del formulario
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (validarFormulario()) {

            const endpoint = idForm === "login" ? "/login" : "/registro";
            const method = "POST";
            const data = formData;

            const headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            };

            //-------------------------------------------------

            const response = await axiosFetch(endpoint, method, data, headers);

            if (response) {
                console.log(`Operación exitosa, ${success}`);
                setModalTitulo('Éxito');
                setModalError(false);
                setModalMensaje(success);
                setModalVisible(true);
            } else {
                console.error("Error durante la operación", error);
                setModalTitulo('Error');
                setModalError(true);
                setModalMensaje(`Error durante la operación. ${error}`);
                setModalVisible(true);
            }

        }
    };

    return {
        formData,
        errors,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        handleSubmit,
        isLoading,
        tituloBotonEnviar,
        modalVisible,
        setModalVisible,
        modalTitulo,
        modalError,
        modalMensaje
    };
};

Cuando leo el estado de success o de error desde handleSubmit nunca obtengo el estado actualizado de success o error al realizar el primer fetch con axios y no sé cómo solucionarlo o por qué React actúa de esta manera.
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { IconoUsuario } from '../icons/interfaz/IconoUsuario';
    import { IconoPassword } from '../icons/interfaz/IconoPassword';
    import { useValidacionLogin } from '../../hooks/login/useValidacionLogin';
    import { Modal } from '../General/Modal';
    
    export const FormLogin = ({
        titulo,
        idForm,
        tituloBotonPrimario,
        tituloBotonTerciario,
        linkBotonTerciario,
    }) => {
        const {
            formData,
            errors,
            handleChange,
            handleBlur, handleSubmit,
            tituloBotonEnviar,
    
            modalVisible,
            setModalVisible,
            modalTitulo,
            modalError,
            modalMensaje
        } = useValidacionLogin(idForm, tituloBotonPrimario);
    
        return (
            <>
               {/*Omito el componente de aqui*/}
    
                <Modal
                    titulo={modalTitulo}
                    error={modalError}
                    mensaje={modalMensaje}
                    visible={modalVisible}
             

       onClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}
            />

        </>
    );
};

Por último el componente de Modal que es el que consume los datos de success o error
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
    export const Modal = ({ titulo, error, visible, mensaje, onClose }) => {
        const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(visible);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (visible) {
                setIsVisible(true);
            }
        }, [visible]);
    
        const handleClose = () => {
            setIsVisible(false);
            if (onClose) {
                onClose();
            }
        };
    
        const botonClassName = error ? 'botonPrimarioError' : 'botonPrimario';
    
        

return (
        <div className={`modal__contenedor ${isVisible ? "visible" : ""}`}>
            <div className={`modal ${error ? 'error' : ''}`}>
                <div className="modal__header">{titulo}</div>

                <div className="modal__cuerpo">
                    {mensaje || 'Acción realizada'}
                </div>

                <div className="modal__boton">
                    <button className={botonClassName} onClick={handleClose}>
                        Aceptar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

Hay algo que no esté viendo, que desconozca o es que no hay forma con Axios? Cualquier pista, ayuda o enfoque diferente es bienvenido.

No se ve la relación entre handleSubmit y el componente FormLogic, no se ve como se esta ejecutando el método handleSubmit

@g.4 la solución fue usar un useeffect para leer esos estados y crear otro estado que establezca los datos a mostrar

Mi solución fue la siguiente:
useEffect(() => {

        isLoading
            ? (idForm === "login"
                ? setTituloBotonEnviar('Iniciando Sesión...')
                : setTituloBotonEnviar('Registrando...'))
            : setTituloBotonEnviar(tituloBotonPrimario)

        if (finFetch) {

            if (success !== false) {
                // console.log(`Operación exitosa, ${success}`);
                setModalTitulo('Éxito');
                setModalError(false);
                setModalMensaje(`Operación realizada con éxito. ${success}`);
                setModalVisible(true);
            } else {
                // console.error("Error durante la operación", error);
                setModalTitulo('Error');
                setModalError(true);
                setModalMensaje(`Error durante la operación. ${error}`);
                setModalVisible(true);
            }
            
            setFinFetch(false);
        }

    }, [isLoading, idForm, tituloBotonPrimario, error, success, finFetch, setFinFetch])

Explicación de la que no estoy seguro:
Parece que los estados de React son asíncronos y no siempre están disponibles al momente de leerlos, en este caso el estado success del fetch aunque es seteado al terminarse el fetch es necesario leerlo con un useeffect por algún motivo, luego ese estado leído guardarlo en otro estado que esté vinculado al componente en que se quiere mostrar. Ha pasado un tiempo desde la solución y no conozco a profundidad React, pero espero que esto pueda servir de ayuda y si me equivoqué en algo corríjanlo

Una explicación, aunque sea breve, hará que se entienda... Nadie va a saber qué ha cambiado cuando la pregunta es extensa (en cuanto a código en múltiples partes...) y la respuesta es solo un bloque de código sin sentido, porque si otra persona tiene el mismo error, lo más seguro es que no esté usando exactamente las mismas variables... Sin embargo con una explicación del problema y cómo resolverlo, el código es casi irrelevante y siempre se entendería muchísimo mejor. Una respuesta de solo código se considera de mala calidad, precisamente por esto mismo. Para + info: [answer]

@Benito-B realmente no entiendo bien por qué los estados de React funcionan como funcionan, parece ser que son asíncronos. La idea es que hay que esperar con un useeffect el estado del fetch para agregarlo a otro estado que esté vinculado directamente al componente

Me refería más bien a una explicación de tus cambios, no de cómo funciona internamente React :) Ver un montón de código en la respuesta que es diferente a la pregunta pero no ver ninguna indicación de qué ha cambiado puede resultar complicado para otras personas que tampoco conozcan el framework
